# Is there any way to wait until every html component is in its position to show website to the user?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am currently developing a mobile website in which I intend to load a series of data to show it to the user. I need to show that website to the user once everything has loaded, so the program can then figure out where is each of the categories of products, so as to give the user the chance to scroll from the top of the website to any category as swiftly as possible.

For that, I have implemented a Promise by which the program tells the website when everything has been processed, so it can hide a loading spinner and show the website. However, there is a slight delay between the processing of that information in my .ts and the positioning and loading of the information I have to show in my .html.

I am making the trick by setting a timeout whenever I set that Promise to be true, but that's rubbish and not reliable at all, as some users can load the information faster than that set timeout, having an unnecessary delay as a result, and some users, with a slower connection, can't get the data in time, making it all useless.

What I want is pretty simple: whenever everything is positioned and ready to be served to the user, I mean, having that loading spinner until the website can be seen without images positioning themselves, list groups out of position, etc. show everything to the user, without using fixed timeouts.

I have read widely about the use of Observables, Promises and so on, but my level of experience and knowledge seems to be rather limited, at the moment.

I am developing the website on Angular 10, with TypeScript and HTML, no jQuery.

[image: Loading screen][image: Full website]

Marked in red, there is an image. In orange, the name of a restaurant. And then, in grey, some of their products. Those are part of several list-groups, which are set as collapsable items.

The problem I am having, then, is that when my timeout falls short, the red square can be anywhere, which disturbs the offsetTop position of those lines called "Tus favoritos", "Entrantes", etc. and disable the scroll by clicking in those names functionality, for example. The other case, in which the timeout is higher than what the user needs is also unacceptable.

Here is some code I'm using. Sorry for the Spanish names.

*establecimiento.html*

```
<div id="panelFinal" *ngIf="datosCargados | async" class="animacion"> ...
</div>

<div id="panelCarga" *ngIf="!datosCargados">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5">
        <div class="spinner-border" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem; color: rgb(224, 96, 11);" role="status">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">Cargando establecimiento...</label>
</div>
```

*establecimiento.ts*

```
cargaDatos() {
    if (this.loadCategorias && this.loadLogo){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.datosCargados = Promise.resolve(true);
      }, 500);
    }
  }

mostrarCompleta() {

    this.authSvc.guardarStorage('tipoCarta', '0');

    const arrayFavs = [];
    for (const prodFav of this.infoProductosFav){
      const fav = `${prodFav.categoriaID}-${prodFav.productoID}`;
      arrayFavs.push(fav);
    }

    if (this.infoProductos.length === 0){
      for (let i = 0; i < this.categorias.length; i++) {
        let idCategoria = '';
        if (i < 9){
          idCategoria = '0' + (i + 1);
        }
        else {
          idCategoria = (i + 1).toString();
        }
        this.firestoreSvc.db.collection('establecimientos').doc(this.establecimientoID).
          collection('categorias').doc(idCategoria).collection('productos').valueChanges().subscribe(val => {
            this.infoProductos[i] = val;
            for (const producto of val.entries()){
              producto[1].Puntuacion = producto[1].Puntuacion.toFixed(1);
              if (producto[1].Disponibilidad === 'Fuera de carta'){
                this.infoProductos[i].splice(producto[0], 1);
                this.categorias[i].Productos = this.infoProductos[i].length.toString();
              }
              if (producto[1].Disponibilidad !== 'Disponible') {
                let idProducto = '';
                const id = producto[0];
                if (id < 9){
                  idProducto = '0' + (id + 1);
                }
                else {
                  idProducto = (id + 1).toString();
                }
                console.log(`${idCategoria}-${idProducto}`);
                if (arrayFavs.includes(`${idCategoria}-${idProducto}`)){
                  const index = arrayFavs.indexOf(`${idCategoria}-${idProducto}`);
                  this.infoProductosFav[index].Indisponibilidad = true;
                }
              }
            }
            this.categorias[i].Productos = this.infoProductos[i].length.toString();
        });
      }
      this.loadCategorias = true;
      this.cargaDatos();
    }

    this.cartaCategorias = false;
    this.cartaCompleta = true;

    let categoriaFocus;
    if (this.authSvc.cargarStorage('CategoriaCarta')) {
      categoriaFocus = this.authSvc.cargarStorage('CategoriaCarta');
    }
    let rect;
    setTimeout( () => {
      if (categoriaFocus && this.establecimientoID === this.authSvc.cargarStorage('idEstablecimiento')) {
        rect = document.getElementById(categoriaFocus).offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, rect - 50);
        localStorage.removeItem('CategoriaCarta');
      }
      for (const categoria of this.categorias){
        if (categoria.Productos !== '0'){
          this.posicionesScroll.push(document.getElementById(categoria.Nombre_Categoria).offsetTop - 75);
          this.sliderCategorias.push(categoria.Nombre_Categoria);
        } else {
          this.posicionesScroll.push(50000);
          this.sliderCategorias.push(categoria.Nombre_Categoria);
        }
      }
      if (this.productosFavoritos){
        this.posicionesScroll.unshift(document.getElementById('favoritos').offsetTop - 75);
        this.sliderCategorias.unshift('favoritos');
        this.posicionesScroll.unshift(0);
        this.sliderCategorias.unshift('busqueda');
      } else {
        this.posicionesScroll.unshift(0);
        this.sliderCategorias.unshift('busqueda');
      }
      document.getElementById('panelFinal').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }, 500);
  }
```

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for the longpost, I tried to be as detailed as possible. Cheers.

Comment: Are you able to share a complete working reproduction of your issue on stackblitz or codesandbox? You're right that `setTimeout` isn't ideal and Observables/Promises are better. Your line of code `this.datosCargados = Promise.resolve(true)` isn't doing anything yet the UI depends on that value to render; consider what you want to happen at that point and perhaps you can find an answer from there.

Comment: Did I get you right you want to display data when it is available?

Comment: If I see it correctly, the 'this.firestoreSvc.db...' part inside the mostrarComplete takes some time to complete, but the call to this.cargaDatos() is made before that first part is done. Within cargaDatos() you just resolve the promise. Try moving that promise logic to the part of the code that actually takes time to finish and only then resolve the promise. Without any stackblitz example I am too inexperienced to give you a working refactored code sample.

Comment: @Ash thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I can't upload the code on stackblitz or codesandbox, as it is part of a much larger code without which it wouldn't work, including Firestore dependencies, etc.

However, I'll be uploading to videos as example of what I want it to do and what it does at this moment.

This is what I want it to do, loading everything, getting it into position and then showing it to the user: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAGdbLsAk-U

This is what it does, showing info as it loads it from Firestore: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vie86iDoXzs

Comment: No, @Yuriy, right the opposite. Wait until everything is loaded and ready and then showing it to the user, so as to avoid that some parts are loaded and others not.

Comment: Thank you, @Erik. But let me clarify that what cargaDatos() does is just making sure that both the Logo (red mark) and the info (black marks) are loaded, and then, if both conditions are fulfilled, it gets to determine that the Promise is true and allows the data to show up.

For some reason, I cannot make that cargaDatos() function to wait until the last piece of info, or the logo itself, has been loaded. What you propose is what I am currently doing, via cargaDatos(), not the promise itself. But thank you!

Comment: You need something like `Promise.all([ request1, request2, ... ]).then(...)` to sync your request and finish at the same time. I think for Angular you might want to use *'rxjs'* with `forkJoin([ ... ]).subscribe(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @AlekseySolovey. I've been working on this since I read it and it seems to be working better than before, but I still cannot get rid of some setTimeouts because of the slight delay between having read the data in the .ts file and having it ready to be served in the .html file. Is there anything that I can do to measure the time between those two instants? I feel that I'm almost there, but I haven't worked it out yet.

Comment: You shouldn't use setTimeout with asynchronous data. Always use Promises / Observers, and resolve them when you need to access the data